# XML Parser in Powershell and move file after validation

Tags: powershell, xml-parsing, xsd-validation

The following script already works pretty good. I can validate my given `xml` file against the `xsd` file and log all validation errors.
My issue is, I want to move the `xml` file, if no validation error occurs. But I don't know where to place the `move-item` statement. I always get the error `file can not moved because it is still in use.` Here is the code. Hopefully someone can help.

```
# Get all XML files in the folder that start with "products"
$xmlFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceDir -Filter products*.xml -File

foreach ($xmlFile in $xmlFiles) {
    $path = $xmlFile.FullName #$sourceDir + $xmlFile

    # Checking if file exits
    if (-not (Test-Path $path)) { 
        Write-Warning "The XML file $path does not exist."
        logger -ErrMessage "File not exits." -log_file $logfile -xml_file $path

    # Checking if file is readable
    } elseif ($xmlFile.IsReadOnly) {
        Write-Warning "XML file not readable: $path"
        logger -ErrMessage "File not readable." -log_file $logfile -xml_file $path
    
    } else {
        # Set up validation settings
        $valSettings = [System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings]::new();
        $valSettings.ValidationType = [System.Xml.ValidationType]::Schema;
        $valSettings.CheckCharacters = $true;
        $valSettings.ValidationFlags = ([System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationFlags]::ProcessIdentityConstraints -bor [System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationFlags]::ReportValidationWarnings)
        $valSettings.Schemas.Add($URL, $xsdFilename);

        # Store validation errors in an array
        $errors = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Xml.Schema.ValidationEventArgs]

        # Create a validation event handler
        $validationHandler = {
            param ([object] $sender, [System.Xml.Schema.ValidationEventArgs] $e)

            $lineNumber = ""
            $linePosition = ""

            # Get the line number and position of the error
          #  if ($e.Exception) {
                $lineNumber = $e.Exception.LineNumber
                $linePosition = $e.Exception.LinePosition
          #  }

            if ($e.Severity -eq [System.Xml.Schema.XmlSeverityType]::Warning) {
                Write-Host("WARNING___: ")
                $errors.Add($e)
                Write-Warning($e.Message, $lineNumber)
                Write-Host("--Line: $lineNumber, Position: $linePosition")
                logger -ErrMessage $e.Message -line $lineNumber -log_file $logfile -xml_file $path
            } 
            elseif ($e.Severity -eq [System.Xml.Schema.XmlSeverityType]::Error) {
                if ($e.Exception -and $e.Exception.Message.StartsWith("The 'text' element is not declared.")) {
                    $e.Severity = [System.Xml.Schema.XmlSeverityType]::Warning
                    Write-Host("WARNING___: ")
                    $errors.Add($e)
                    Write-Warning($e.Exception.Message)
                    Write-Host("--Line: $lineNumber, Position: $linePosition")
                    logger -ErrMessage $e.Message -line $lineNumber -log_file $logfile -xml_file $path
                }
                else {
                    $errors.Add($e)
                    Write-Warning $e.Message;
                    Write-Host("--Line: $lineNumber, Position: $linePosition");
                    if (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($logfile)) {
                        #write-host $e.Exception.GetType().FullName
                        logger -ErrMessage $e.Message -line $lineNumber -log_file $logfile -xml_file $path
                    } 
                }
            } 
        }

        # Set up validation event handler to capture errors
        #$valSettings.ValidationEventHandler += {$errors.Add($_)}#/ turn it on, if 'Add_ValidationEventHandler' runs into error

        $destination = "C:\Users\BeKa-Coca\Downloads\XML_Validation\$xmlFile"

        try {
            # Read each xml node, validate it and close the xml file
        $valSettings.Add_ValidationEventHandler($validationHandler)   
        $xmlReader = [System.Xml.XmlReader]::Create([System.IO.File]::OpenRead($path), $valSettings);
            while ($xmlReader.Read()) { }
            $xmlReader.Close()
            #Copy-Item $xmlFile.FullName $destination
            #Move-Item $xmlFile.FullName $destination -Force

        } catch{
            $lineNumber = ""
            $linePosition = ""
         #   if ($_.Exception) {
                $lineNumber = [regex]::Match($_.Exception.Message, "Zeile (\d+)").Groups[1].Value
                $linePosition = [regex]::Match($_.Exception.Message, "Position (\d+)").Groups[1].Value
         #   }
            $errorDesc = $_.Exception.Message  
            write-warning $_.Exception.Message
            Write-Host("--Line: $lineNumber, Position: $linePosition")
            logger -ErrMessage $errorDesc -line $lineNumber -log_file $logfile -xml_file $path
        }
        finally {

            # make sure the xml reader is closed even if an exception occurs
           if ($xmlReader) {
                $xmlReader.Dispose()

                # Copy / move only valid xml files
                If (-not($errors)) {
                    #Copy-Item $xmlFile.FullName $destination -Force
                    Move-Item $xmlFile.FullName $destination -Force
                } else {WRITE-Host "ERROR!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"}
            }
        }
    } #End If-else

             #Copy-Item $xmlFile.FullName $destination
             #logger -ErrMessage "The file is in use by another process." -log_file $logfile -xml_file $path

 } #End ForEach Loop
```

The created xmlReader gets closed, before i try to move the file. But the file is still blocks and I don't know why.

Comment: At 1st gance: **[1]** If you add `-File` to the Get-ChildItem line you are sure to get **existing** FileInfo objects (no need to test if it exists) **[2]** Because of [1], inside your loop variable `$xmlFile` is an object with many properties, one of which is `.FullName`, so use that for variable `$path` and use property `$xmlFile.IsReadOnly` instead of getting the item again. **[3]** `$xmlReader.Dispose()` also closes, so you can remove `$xmlReader.close()` in the finally block. **[4]** move the `Move-Item ..` line away from the finally block and put it as last line in the `try{}` block.

Comment: **[5]** Instead of testing `if ($xmlReader -ne $null)`, just do `if ($xmlReader)`

Comment: I changed my code, but moving the file, is still not possible. I receive the error `xml file is locked by another process`. where should I place `$xmlFile.IsReadOnly`? Is this the key, to get it run the right way without running into an error?

Comment: You may have changed the code, but not the post on SO, so we can't tell what you did.. Replace `if ((Get-Item $path).IsReadOnly)` with `if ($xmlFile.IsReadOnly)`

Comment: Regarding to the given advices, I edit my original post. But it still runs into the same error: `file could not be moved, because it is locked by another process`. Why does the `xmlReader.close()` does not close the `object` correctly? To run the script, I use the following comand in the windows console `. ./xml_validation_logging_v02.ps1`. Maybe this cause the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, try this new rewrite of your code.
Of course, I cannot see what your function `logger` does exactly, but I can't imagine that is causing the file to stay locked.

I did change the code now to initialize all validation settings variables on top AND adde this: `$valSettings.CloseInput = $true`, to make sure the underlying stream or TextReader gets closed. See [CloseInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.closeinput?view=netframework-4.0#system-xml-xmlreadersettings-closeinput)

```
# Set up validation settings
$valSettings = [System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings]::new()
$valSettings.ValidationType  = [System.Xml.ValidationType]::Schema
$valSettings.CheckCharacters = $true
$valSettings.CloseInput      = $true  # close the underlying stream or TextReader when the reader is closed
$valSettings.ValidationFlags = ([System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationFlags]::ProcessIdentityConstraints -bor 
                                [System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationFlags]::ReportValidationWarnings)
$valSettings.Schemas.Add($URL, $xsdFilename)

# Store validation errors in an List object
$errors = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Xml.Schema.ValidationEventArgs]

# find all xml files in the source directory
$xmlFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceDir -Filter 'products*.xml' -File

foreach ($xmlFile in $xmlFiles) {
    $errors.Clear()
    $path = $xmlFile.FullName
    if ($xmlFile.IsReadOnly) {
        Write-Warning "XML file not readable: $path"
        logger -ErrMessage "File not readable." -log_file $logfile -xml_file $path
        continue   # skip this file and proceed with the next
    } 

    # Create a validation event handler
    $validationHandler = {
        param ([object] $sender, [System.Xml.Schema.ValidationEventArgs] $e)
        # Get the line number and position of the error
        $lineNumber   = $e.Exception.LineNumber
        $linePosition = $e.Exception.LinePosition

        if ($e.Severity -eq [System.Xml.Schema.XmlSeverityType]::Warning) {
            Write-Host "WARNING___: "
            [void]$errors.Add($e)
            Write-Warning ($e.Message, $lineNumber)
            Write-Host "--Line: $lineNumber, Position: $linePosition"
            logger -ErrMessage $e.Message -line $lineNumber -log_file $logfile -xml_file $path
        } 
        elseif ($e.Severity -eq [System.Xml.Schema.XmlSeverityType]::Error) {
            if ($e.Exception.Message -like "The 'text' element is not declared*") {
                Write-Host "ERROR___: "
                [void]$errors.Add($e)
                Write-Warning $e.Exception.Message
                Write-Host "--Line: $lineNumber, Position: $linePosition"
                logger -ErrMessage $e.Message -line $lineNumber -log_file $logfile -xml_file $path
            }
            else {
                [void]$errors.Add($e)
                Write-Warning $e.Message
                Write-Host "--Line: $lineNumber, Position: $linePosition" 
                # write-host $e.Exception.GetType().FullName
                logger -ErrMessage $e.Message -line $lineNumber -log_file $logfile -xml_file $path
            }
        } 
    }

    $destination = 'C:\Users\BeKa-Coca\Downloads\XML_Validation'  # just the path here

    try {
        # Read each xml node, validate it and close the xml file
        $valSettings.Add_ValidationEventHandler($validationHandler)   
        $xmlReader = [System.Xml.XmlReader]::Create([System.IO.File]::OpenRead($path), $valSettings)
        while (!$xmlReader.EOF -and $xmlReader.Read()) {}
        $xmlReader.Dispose()
        $xmlReader = $null
        # Copy / move only valid xml files
        if ($errors.Count -eq 0) {
            #$xmlFile | Copy-Item -Destination $destination
            $xmlFile | Move-Item -Destination $destination -Force
        }
    } 
    catch{
        $lineNumber   = [regex]::Match($_.Exception.Message, "Zeile (\d+)").Groups[1].Value
        $linePosition = [regex]::Match($_.Exception.Message, "Position (\d+)").Groups[1].Value
        $errorDesc    = $_.Exception.Message
        Write-Warning $errorDesc
        Write-Host "--Line: $lineNumber, Position: $linePosition"
        logger -ErrMessage $errorDesc -line $lineNumber -log_file $logfile -xml_file $path
    }
    finally {
        # make sure the xml reader is closed even if an exception occurs
        if ($xmlReader) { $xmlReader.Dispose() }
        $xmlReader = $null
    }
} # End foreach loop
```

Comment: Thanks for help. But it runs still into the same error. File is locked and can not be moved. `+             $xmlFile | Move-Item -Destination $destination -Force
+                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\BeKa-C..._230505_401.xml:FileInfo) [Move-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MoveFileInfoItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand
`Any other advices to solve the issue? Does it have something to do with the command I use to start the script   `. .\xml_validation_logging_v03.ps1`?

Comment: Thanks. It works. Correct files get moved. Here the logger function: `function logger {
[CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$ErrMessage,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$line,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$log_file,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$xml_file
    )
    $timestamp = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    $logMsg = "[$timestamp] -- [Source: $xml_file] -- [Line: $line] -- [ERROR] $ErrMessage"
    Add-Content -Path $log_file -Value $logMsg }`

Comment: There is one last issuue. If `$xmlFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceDir -Filter 'products*.xml' -File` get more than one xml file, one validation error gets logged twice. I I validate only one file, the error logging works correct and just logs one error. I guess it has something to do with the loop.

Comment: I did a couple more tests. As long as I only have one xml file to validate, everythings works as expacted and each error gets  longs once. But if I get two xml files in the folder, all errors for the second file gets logged double. What could be the reason for that issue?

Comment: Would you like to check it one more time? I would appreciate your feedback. Have a nice day.

Comment: @the_floor I have made some tiny changes. If you still get doubled messages in the log, please could you post these in full

Comment: Great! Awsome. It works. Thank you so much. Regarding the error handling: Is there something elso, that makes sence to log as well to improve the error handling? Enjoy the rest of the day.

Comment: @the_floor Ah, that's good to hear  your logging function looks fine. If you feel my answer solved your problem, please  mark this question 'done'. You can see in the [tour] how to do that.